# TFS 2015 RC Collection upgrade failed

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Today I downloaded and installed new Team Foundation Server 2015 RC from Microsoft.
When I started upgrade process everything well fine until Upgrade process started servicing and upgrading collections.
I have 2 attached collections. One is exported collection from Visual Studio Online and is small. On this collection process ended successfully.
Second collection what i using daily ended on upgrade step 126/~608.
I tried this process few times but every time ended bad.

I tried upgrade all from last TFS 2013 Update 4

```
  1 error(s) occurred while executing upd_SecuritySharedToDev14M72.sql script.
Failed batch starts on line: 1.

Error: 3732, Level: 16, State: 1, Batch Line: 1, Script Line: 1
Message: Cannot drop type 'typ_AccessControlListTable' because it is being referenced by object 'prc_SetSnapshotInstanceSecurityData'. There may be other objects that reference this type.
================ Failed batch begin ==========================
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE name = 'typ_AccessControlListTable' AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')) DROP TYPE typ_AccessControlListTable
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE name = 'typ_DeleteTokenTable' AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')) DROP TYPE typ_DeleteTokenTable
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE name = 'typ_PermissionTable' AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')) DROP TYPE typ_PermissionTable
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE name = 'typ_TokenRenameTable' AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')) DROP TYPE typ_TokenRenameTable
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE name = 'typ_TokenTable' AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')) DROP TYPE typ_TokenTable
================ Failed batch end ============================
```

I tried the same collection too like:
Few days older collection version.
Collection version from TFS 2013 Update 3 and ended with no success.

Know someone how to solve this issue ? 
Thanks for answers and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found solution.
Here is solution i found based on information provided by MS person.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1289654

1. I Installed again TFS 2013 Update 4 and setup all services like before i started upgrade process to TFS 2015 RC.
2. Detached problematic collection (there were few warnings about SQL server edition features enabled, tfs build agents, controllers warnings)
3. Attached collection again (there were few warnings about existing report server reports)
4. Installed TFS 2015 RC over TFS 2013 U4 like before
5. Followed steps in upgrade wizard and continued with standard upgrade process
6. Upgrade process ended with success on both collections

Comment: Please include the relevant information in the answer. Posting nothing but an off-site link is not considered an answer on Stack Overflow.